# Javascript - Is it possible to pass arguments to a function that already has arguments?

Tags: javascript, function, arguments

Is it possible to add parameters to a function passed as a parameter?
I arrived at this attempt:

```
function one() {

  const args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);

  const func = args[0];

  const moreArgs = [5]; /// i want number 5 to be arg2

  func.apply(this, moreArgs);

}


function two(arg1, arg2) {
  console.log(arg1);
  console.log(arg2);
}

const call2 = function(){

  return two(3);

}


one(call2)
```

/// The output I get is :

```
3

undefined
```

/// Output goal:

```
3

5
```

Can this behaviour or something similar be accomplished in javascript?

Comment: No, you cannot pass a single parameter to a function that requires two parameters and expect it to magically figure out the second parameter

Comment: Maybe you’re looking for `bind` instead: `const f = (a, b) => console.log(a, b); const g = f.bind(this, 3); g(5);` produces `3 5`. `.call` and `.apply` immediately call the function with the parameters already provided so far.

Comment: Your `one()` function is a really (and unnecessary) complicated `arguments[0](5)`

Comment: In your example, you call `one`, which calls `call2` with the argument `5`. But `call2` doesn’t take arguments. Nothing is done with them. Did you mean `const call2 = function(arg){ return two(3, arg); }`?

Answer (score 0):

Use `two(3, ...arguments);` to achieve something like this:

```js
function one() {
  const args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
  const func = args[0];
  const moreArgs = [5];
  func.apply(this, moreArgs);
}


function two(arg1, arg2) {
  console.log(arg1);
  console.log(arg2);
}

const call2 = function(){
  return two(3, ...arguments); // this line was modified
}

one(call2)
```